# Delphi Firemonkey mobile app will crash when using Teechart

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe, firemonkey, teechart

I am developing an application, I have a main form and a button, when I click on a button I show another form that there is a TeeChart on it, when I close the second form and return to the Main Form the will crash (both ios Device and Simulator) and in log console on mac there is a "Exit with code:1" log. I test it on an Android device but it works fine. Any idea?

Comment: how are we suppose to know? Post the related code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, when you remove the graph form "Auto create forms" (in project options) and new the graph form in code and then close and free the graph form, the problem will happen,
Instead let it be in "auto create forms" and when you want to show the graph use

```
frmgraph.show();
frmgraph.BringToFront();
```

and instead of closing the form use

```
Hide();
```